# count true false sum values by time thresholds in r

Tags: r, time, count

I have a student dataset that includes responses to questions as right or wrong. There is also a time variable in seconds. I would like to create a time flag to record number of correct and incorrect responses by `1 minute` `2 minute` and `3 minute` thresholds.  Here is a sample dataset.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 gender = c("m","f","m","f","m"),
                 age = c(11,12,12,13,14),
                 i1 = c(1,0,NA,1,0),
                 i2 = c(0,1,0,"1]",1),
                 i3 = c("1]",1,"1]",0,"0]"),
                 i4 = c(0,"0]",1,1,0),
                 i5 = c(1,1,NA,"0]","1]"),
                 i6 = c(0,0,"0]",1,1),
                 i7 = c(1,"1]",1,0,0),
                 i8 = c(0,0,0,"1]","1]"),
                 i9 = c(1,1,1,0,NA),
                 time = c(115,138,148,195, 225))


 > df
  id gender age i1 i2 i3 i4   i5 i6 i7 i8 i9 time
1  1      m  11  1  0 1]  0    1  0  1  0  1  115
2  2      f  12  0  1  1 0]    1  0 1]  0  1  138
3  3      m  12 NA  0 1]  1 <NA> 0]  1  0  1  148
4  4      f  13  1 1]  0  1   0]  1  0 1]  0  195
5  5      m  14  0  1 0]  0   1]  1  0 1] NA  225
```

The minute thresholds are represented by a `]` sign at the right side of the score.

For example for the `id = 3`, the `1-minute` threshold is at item `i3` , the `2-minute` threshold is at item `i6`. Each student might have different time thresholds.

I need to create flagging variables to count number of correct and incorrect responses by the `1-min` `2-min` and `3-min` thresholds.

How can I achieve the desired dataset as below.

```
> df1
  id gender age i1 i2 i3 i4   i5 i6 i7 i8 i9 time one_true one_false two_true two_false three_true three_false
1  1      m  11  1  0 1]  0    1  0  1  0  1  115        2         1       NA        NA         NA          NA
2  2      f  12  0  1  1 0]    1  0 1]  0  1  138        2         2        4         3         NA          NA
3  3      m  12 NA  0 1]  1 <NA> 0]  1  0  1  148        1         1        2         2         NA          NA
4  4      f  13  1 1]  0  1   0]  1  0 1]  0  195        2         0        3         2          5           3
5  5      m  14  0  1 0]  0   1]  1  0 1] NA  225        1         2        2         3          4           4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dplyr pipe that produces what you want.

I'm optionally using `xfun::n2w` to convert `1` to `"one"`, etc. If you can accept strict numbers, then you don't need this.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_*
# library(xfun) # n2w, convert numbers to words
df %>%
  select(-gender, -age, -time) %>%
  mutate(across(-id, as.character)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  arrange(id, name) %>%
  mutate(
    grp = 1L + cumsum(grepl("]", lag(value), fixed=TRUE)),
    grp = xfun::n2w(grp),
    num = if_else(gsub("[^0-9]", "", value) == "1", "true", "false"),
    .by = id) %>%
  filter(
    any(grepl("]", value, fixed = TRUE)), 
    .by = c(id, grp)) %>%
  count(id, grp, num) %>%
  filter(!is.na(num)) %>%
  mutate(n = cumsum(n), .by = c(id, num)) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id, names_sep = "_",
    names_from = c("grp", "num"), values_from = "n"
  ) %>%
  left_join(df, ., by = "id")
#   id gender age i1 i2 i3 i4   i5 i6 i7 i8 i9 time one_false one_true two_false two_true three_false three_true
# 1  1      m  11  1  0 1]  0    1  0  1  0  1  115         1        2        NA       NA          NA         NA
# 2  2      f  12  0  1  1 0]    1  0 1]  0  1  138         2        2         3        4          NA         NA
# 3  3      m  12 NA  0 1]  1 <NA> 0]  1  0  1  148         1        1         2        2          NA         NA
# 4  4      f  13  1 1]  0  1   0]  1  0 1]  0  195        NA        2         3        5           1          4
# 5  5      m  14  0  1 0]  0   1]  1  0 1] NA  225         2        1         4        4           3          3
```

This is using `.by=`, so required `dplyr_1.1.0` or newer.

Most of the work is done on a temporary frame that returns `id` and the intended summary columns `one_false` and beyond.

- `mutate(across(-id, as.character))` because `pivot_longer` requires compatible classes, and your sample data here has some columns int, some chr.
- `pivot_longer` reshapes from "wide" to three columns: `id`, `name` (`"i1", "i2", ...`), and `value` (`"1", "0", "1]", ...`)
- `mutate(grp...)` condition the groups such that everything up until the first occurrence of `]` is in group `"one"`, `"two"`, etc; the use of `xfun:n2w` to go from `2` to `"two"` is purely aesthetic, you can do without if you can accept column names starting with numbers, ala `1_true` (assuming you mutate `num` as well);
- `mutate(num...)` converts your `1`s and `0`s to `"true"` and `"false"`; this is mostly aesthetic, included to match your intended output; if you would prefer just `0` and `1`, then you'd still need to remove the `]` in order to count things correctly
- `filter(any(...))` removes rows that do not end in a value with `]`
- `count` *counts* (weird) by the groups
- `mutate(n=cumsum(n))` by different grouping ensures your `one_true` and `two_true` are cumulative
- `pivot_wider` converts multiple rows into columns, undoing our first effort
- we bring that summary back to the original `df` with `left_join`